# spring boot with mongo atlas is not working

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-atlas

NOTE:- Edited Some typo

I am trying to connect my spring boot application with Mongo atlas. I have configured Atlas, I am able to connect to atlas via Mongo compass too and I have created a database with a collection via canvas. then I copied the uri from atlas's connect tab selected java as driver, tried with all the version given one by one but nothing worked. my code is as following.

my controller

```
    @GetMapping("/candidate")
public String getCandidate(Model model){
    model.addAttribute("cdto", new CandidateDto());
    return "candidate";
}

@PostMapping("candidate")
public String postCandidate(@ModelAttribute ("cdto") @Valid CandidateDto cdto){

    cservice.addCandidate(cdto);
    return "redirect:/candidate";
}
```

here is my Entity class

```
    import lombok.Data;

    @Data
    @Document(collection="candidate")
    public class Candidate {
        private String name;
        private String age;
        private String branch;
        private String institute;
        private String pasout;
        private String mobile;
        private String email;
        private String tenth;
        private String wealth;
        private String degree;


    }
```

here is my dto class

```
    import lombok.Data;
    @Data
    public class CandidateDto {

      private String name;
      private String age;
      private String branch;
      private String institute;
      private String pasout;
      private String mobile;
      private String email;
      private String tenth;
      private String wealth;
      private String degree;


  }
```

here is my Repository

```
    public interface CandidateRepository extends MongoRepository<Candidate, String> {

    }
```

here is my service implementation

```
    @Override
public void addCandidate(CandidateDto cdto) {
    Candidate ca=new Candidate();

    ca.setName(cdto.getName());
    ca.setAge(cdto.getAge());
    ca.setBranch(cdto.getBranch());
    ca.setDegree(cdto.getDegree());
    ca.setEmail(cdto.getEmail());
    ca.setInstitute(cdto.getInstitute());
    ca.setMobile(cdto.getMobile());
    ca.setPasout(cdto.getPasout());
    ca.setTenth(cdto.getTenth());
    ca.setTwelth(cdto.getTwelth());
    crepo.save(ca);

}
```

and this is my application.properties

```
    spring.data.mongodb.database=ndtcdb



    spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://myadmin:mypassword@cluster0-shard-00-00-vfmqk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-01-vfmqk.mongodb.net:27017,cluster0-shard-00-02-vfmqk.mongodb.net:27017/test?ssl=true&replicaSet=Cluster0-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

## Edit:- adding this code for my application class

```
    @SpringBootApplication
    public class NdtcApplication {

         public static void main(String[] args) {
         SpringApplication.run(NdtcApplication.class, args);
         }

   }
```

and following is my pom.xml

```
    <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/jstl -->
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
     <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
       </dependency>
       </dependencies>
```

and this is the error I am receiving

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/MongoCredential
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.findConstructorBindingAnnotatedConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:62) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.getBindConstructor(ConfigurationPropertiesBindConstructorProvider.java:48) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBean$BindMethod.forType(ConfigurationPropertiesBean.java:311) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.validate(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:63) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurationPropertiesBeanDefinitionValidator.java:45) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:286) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:174) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:706) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:532) ~[spring-context-5.2.5.RELEASE.jar:5.2.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
at com.ndtc.NdtcApplication.main(NdtcApplication.java:10) [classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.2.6.RELEASE.jar:2.2.6.RELEASE]
    Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mongodb.MongoCredential
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_161]
    ... 24 common frames omitted
```

Kindly Help, Its been 3 days I am struggling but not able to solve it

Comment: Do you have a dependency for `spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb`?

Comment: Yes, let me please also put the pom.xml here

Comment: Hmmm so you can try to add dependency on driver:
`<dependency>  
<groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
  <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
  <version>3.11.2</version></dependency>`

Comment: Just tried but error remains

Answer (score 0):

In case if it will help someone, after Lots of search and trials, I finally solved it, all I did was to add this dependency in my pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

I don't know why I was needed to add this dependency when I already added spring - boot - starter - data - mongodb. anyways But it solved my problem